# C# ASP.NET GA4 Upgrade Issue Error: invalid_grant for Google Analytics 4 using Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4 Nuget Package

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-analytics-4

[image]

Current switching over from Google Anaytics V3 to V4. I was provided with a new user email and am running the following code.

```
string[] scopes = { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly };

//loading the Key file
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
{
    Scopes = scopes
}.FromCertificate(certificate));

var data = GetGAData(credential, "52424234234", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90), DateTime.Now);

public static GetReportsResponse GetGAData(ServiceAccountCredential credential, string viewId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string nextPageToken = null)
{
    using (var svc = new AnalyticsReportingService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential
    }))
{
    var mets = new List<Metric>
        {
            new Metric
            {
                Alias = "Page Views",
                Expression = "ga:pageViews"
            }
        };

    var dims = new List<Dimension>
        {
            new Dimension { Name = "ga:pagePath" }
        };

    var dateRange = new DateRange
    {
        StartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        EndDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    };

    var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
    {
        DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
        Dimensions = dims,
        Metrics = mets,
        ViewId = viewId,
        PageToken = nextPageToken
    };
    var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest
    {
        ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest },
    };
    var batchRequest = svc.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest);
    var response = batchRequest.Execute();

    return response;
}
```

}

I get this error message back from google on the new username that was provided:

Message = "Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid JWT Signature.", Uri:"""

If I use the old username that was being used in the V3 implementation it works fine. However that user is tied to an old profile ID that is no longer being used so I can no longer use that user.

Comment: Are you still using UA? it has been Expired and you should pass to Google Data API which is called GA4

Comment: I'm using GA4, I just confirmed.

Comment: The code you have shared, is related to Universal and not GA4

Comment: So this code is not GA4? Can you provide a link or doc reference to an ASP.NET C# implementation for GA4. Please see the screenshot I just added it shows I'm using the V4 nuget package in Visual Studio. I uninstalled V3.

Comment: The standard libraries are provided here in Java,
Python,
Node.js,
.NET,
PHP and 
Go ,  languages : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong library. I was thrown off by the fact that the doc and nuget shows the library as being a beta version but appearently thats what your suppose to use. See below:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries